# Custom Plugin - Blacklist/Whitelist domain email and change user role - Suggestions

Tags: user-roles, domain

i've a website with SSO Saml. I need to have a blacklist/whitelist based on domain email and after this is checked i need to have a change role by double check between profession/specialty parameters that return from login.

I've developped a plugin to do so. Everything works fine but i need to know if it'sthe right way or it could be a cleaner way. I've based it on login check, but i have the doubt that it can be expensive in performance. (i think every time a page load it check user role).
Are there some hooks to do the same thing but in wordpress registration process? So i can do it only once.

Here's the code. I use bboress forum so i have two roles per user -Thanks for any suggestions.

```
// USER ROLE RETURN 
function get_user_role($user_id) {
    global $wp_roles;

    $roles = array();
    $user = new WP_User( $user_id );
    if ( !empty( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {
    foreach ( $user->roles as $role )
        $roles[] .= translate_user_role( $role );
    }
    return implode(', ',$roles);   
} 
// END USER ROLE

/*
Case 1 - user has blacklist email domain - wp role 'restircted', bbpress role 'blocked'
Case 2 - user has whitelist email - wp role 'editor', bbpress role 'bbpress_participant'
Case 3 - user has one profession and one of three specialty - wp role 'role3' , bbpress role 'bbpress_participant'
Case 4 - user has no blacklist, whitelist or prefession/specialty check - WP role and bbpress role assigned automatically by Wordpress. 
*/

// LOGIN FUNCTIONS
//Get user role and Filter Blacklist Whitelist with array
function loginUserRole() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_email = $current_user ->user_email;
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $user_role = get_user_role( $user_id );
    $user_profession= get_field('profession' , 'user_'. $user_id );
    $user_specialty= get_field('specialty' , 'user_'. $user_id );

    if (!is_admin() AND is_user_logged_in() AND ($user_role != 'administrator, bbp_keymaster')) {

    $blacklist = ['@test.com'];
    $whitelist= ['test1@test.com']; 
    $trovato_blacklist=false;
    $trovato_whitelist=false;
    
    foreach ($blacklist as $black) {     
        $find_email_black = strpos($user_email, $black);
        
        if ($find_email_black !== false){
            $trovato_blacklist=true; 
        } 
    } 

    if ($trovato_blacklist) {
        // cambia il ruolo nella blacklist
        $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
        $u->set_role('restricted');
        $u->add_role('bbp_blocked');
    
        foreach ($whitelist as $white) {     
            $find_email_white = strpos($user_email, $white);
            
            if ($find_email_white !== false){
                $trovato_whitelist=true; 
            } else { echo $find_email_white; }
            } 
                if ($trovato_whitelist) {
                // change user role for Whitelist
                $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
                
                $u->set_role('editor');
                $u->add_role('bbp_participant');
                }
    }
    // after Blacklist, Whitelist check user profession and change role 
    else {
        // check user profession
        if ($user_profession == 'profession' )
        {
            //check user specialty 
            $specialty = array(
                'specialty1','specialty2','specialty3'
            );

            if (in_array($user_specialty , $specialty ) ) 
            {
                //change user role for profession/specialty check
                $u = new WP_User( $user_id );
                $u->set_role('role3');
                $u->add_role('bbp_participant');
            }
            
          }
    
        }
     }
   }

   add_action('init', 'loginUserRole');
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you process all users once (using a WP-CLI command if your db is big and response timeout is a possible risk) and then check a user each time they try to change their email (using wp_update_user filter - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/).

Comment: @diegop, I know you didn't ask for this, but take it as a friendly advice - if you avoid using non-English language in variable names and code comments, and you apply the WP/PHP coding standards, you'll make your code a lot easier for others to read, understand and improve.

Comment: Thanks for precious suggestion!!!!!